# I'm writing a simple kodi addon: what should be the url to play a torrent file with Quasar?

Tags: python, url, add-on, kodi, torrent

Just for fun, I'm trying to write a Kodi addon for personal use capable of playing some torrent files through Quasar addon. Having my torrent files on a web site, I'm trying to play the videos, but I don't know what value assign to the **url** variable in this simple example:

```
addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
xbmcplugin.setContent(addon_handle, 'movies')
url = 'http://mysite/video.torrent'
li = xbmcgui.ListItem('First test!', iconImage='DefaultVideo.png')
xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=addon_handle, url=url, listitem=li)
xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(addon_handle)
```

The example above doesn't work as I suspected, although it works if points directly to a video file. Is there any way to tell kodi that is a torrent file or specify in some way the plugin needed to the play the torrent?

Any help?

Comment: You need to use lib torrent module for kodi to play the torrent file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I use Quasar to watch torrents. I think I have to use: url = "plugin://plugin.video.quasar/<whatever>", but I can't find any info about its correct use.